# Animation is only visible the first time Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a project in compose, i have a map with markers, when you click a marker it shows a dialog with the info of the selected one, i'm trying to add an animation to this composable when it appears and disappears but it only shows the first time and only the start animation (i've attached a video).

This is the code where the composable is showed and where the animation is applied with a SideEffect:

```
@Composable
fun DiscoverScreen(
  navController: NavController,
  viewModel: DiscoverViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

  val mapState = viewModel.mapState.value
  val selectedCluster = viewModel.selectedCluster.value
  val isVisibleState = remember { MutableTransitionState(false) }

  SideEffect {
    isVisibleState.targetState = selectedCluster != null
  }

  Scaffold(
    bottomBar = { SunsetBottomNavigation(navController) },
    content = { paddingValues ->
      Box(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
      ) {
        DiscoverContent(
          mapState = mapState,
          setupClusterManager = viewModel::setupClusterManager,
          calculateZoneViewCenter = viewModel::calculateZoneLatLngBounds,
          onClusterClicked = { clusterItem ->
            viewModel.selectedCluster.value = clusterItem
          }
        )

        if (selectedCluster != null) {
          Box(
            modifier = Modifier
              .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
              .padding(24.dp)
          ) {
            AnimatedVisibility(
              visibleState = isVisibleState,
              enter = slideInVertically(initialOffsetY = { it }, animationSpec = tween(500)),
              exit = slideOutVertically(
                targetOffsetY = { it },
                animationSpec = tween(500)
              ) + fadeOut(
                animationSpec = tween(
                  durationMillis = 300
                )
              )
            ) {
              TestSelectedComposable(selectedCluster) { viewModel.selectedCluster.value = null }
            }
          }
        }

      }
    }
  )
}
```

This is the dialog that appears:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalGlideComposeApi::class)
@Composable fun TestSelectedComposable(selectedCluster: ZoneClusterItem, onClose: () -> Unit) {
  Card(
    modifier = Modifier
      .fillMaxWidth()
      .height(140.dp),
    backgroundColor = Color.White,
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp),
    elevation = 2.dp,
  ) {
    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
      Box() {
        GlideImage(
          modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .fillMaxWidth(0.4f),
          model = "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/04/78/75/360_F_104787586_63vz1PkylLEfSfZ08dqTnqJqlqdq0eXx.jpg",
          contentDescription = "",
          contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )
        Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)) {
          RoundedCloseIconButton { onClose() }
        }
      }
      Column(
        modifier = Modifier
          .fillMaxSize()
          .padding(8.dp)
      ) {
        Text(text = selectedCluster.title, style = primaryBoldHeadlineS)
        Text(text = selectedCluster.snippet, style = secondaryRegularBodyL)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Video where it shows the animation only the first time and only the start animation: https://drive.google.com/file/d/177G5SfSZvoZfiMO6aT6KzSgXnccsszpI/view?usp=share_link